# How do you describe a pie pan in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, comida

Even my Mexican friends don't know how to say "pie pan" or "pie tin" in Spanish.  Google isn't much help, either.

How can I effectively communicate about a pie pan?

Examples:

Disposable, single-use pie pan, made of aluminum:

[image: Aluminum pie pan]

Multi-use metal pie pan:

[image: Metal pie pan]

Glass pie pan:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The first image that comes to my mind is the traditional apple pie dish, baked on top of an aluminum foil plate. It's a hard item to find in Spanish cuisine, but I would use *molde para tartas* o *plato para tartas*

Comment: +1. Looking around on a department store website, the closest approximations I can find to the Google image results for *pie pan* are simply labelled as *molde*.

Answer (score 5):

In Spain, *pay* doesn't exist.  *Tarta* is a generic word used for everything that is a dessert that is round; specialized deserts exist, like *bizcocho* which is a cake with a hole - like pound cake. Apple pie for example may be *tarta de manzana*. Pie, like American pie, is not so common so there is not a specific word for it.
The pan may be called *molde para tartas* because it basically means that you want to make a dessert in the shape of a pie.

Comment: Isn't *bizcocho* a synonym of *coca*, and void of implication about shape?

Comment: @PeterTaylor, well, depending what you mean by "coca" :D But yes, *bizcocho* can be of any shape, it's a sponge cake.

Comment: There is no pay in English here at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a lot on the region, but what I've seen on Northern Mexico (more specifically Chihuahua) is **"Base para Pay"** (and yes usually pie here is "pay") or **"Corteza para Pay"**

Comment: There is no pay in the English. It's pie pan. Pie.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you read my reply I'm not making any claim that there is a "pay in the English", just that the word "pay" is used in Mexico as a translation of the English "pie" instead of "tarta".